# Return a list of lists from elements grouped by another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I don't know how to describe my question, so I will just show an example here.

```
A B
1 3
1 4
2 5
2 8
2 6
3 6
3 8
4 10
4 1
```

The data frame has two column A and B. I want to make it return a list like this.

```
[[3,4],[5,8,6],[6,8],[10,1]]
```

As you see, this is grouped by `A` and returns a list of numbers in `B` column. To be noticed, the order of elements in `B` DOESN'T CHANGE. Also the sub-lists have the same order as shown in column A. (`[3,4]` from group 1, `[5,8,6]` from group 2, etc)

Suppose dataframe is ordered by A already. I know how to use for loop to do it, but my dataset has 1 billion records. So I am looking for some efficient and clean code for this problem.

Comment: show your inefficient approach first

Comment: For a given value of A, what if there are duplicate values in B.  Do you want the set, or do you want to see the duplicates?

Comment: I guess you could use `df.groupby('A').B.apply(pd.Series.tolist).tolist()` but if you really have 1 billion records as you claim, I doubt anything would be fast enough for you

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thank you! This works perfect. Now really take much time!

Comment: @Alexander Yeah, i forget to mention that. Sorry about it. I consider duplicates. :)

Comment: What if the items are not sorted by A?  For example, if the values in column A where 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, ...?  If you need the dups, then the comment by COLDSPEED is probably the best solution.

Comment: @Alexander Yeah, that's right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to group on the first column `A`, then get the unique values in `B` (assuming you only want unique values and not duplicates).  After you've done that, use a lambda expression to convert each of the np.array values to lists, and then convert the resulting series to a list using `.tolist()`.

```
>>> df.groupby('A', sort=False)['B'].apply(list).tolist()
```

Or,

```
>>> [list(v) for v in df.groupby('A', sort=False)['B'].unique()]
```

Or,

```
>>> df.groupby('A', sort=False)['B'].apply(lambda x: x.unique().tolist()).tolist()
```

```
[[3, 4], [5, 8, 6], [6, 8], [10, 1]]
```

I would also recommend not sorting the groupby operation.

Here are some timing comparisons for anyone who is interested:

```
df_ = pd.concat([df] * 10000)  # Set-up larger dataframe with 90k rows.

%timeit df_.groupby('A', sort=False)['B'].unique().apply(list).tolist()
# 100 loops, best of 3: 5.9 ms per loop

%timeit df_.groupby('A', sort=False)['B'].apply(list).tolist()
# 100 loops, best of 3: 6.79 ms per loop

%timeit list(map(list, df_.groupby('A', sort=False)['B'].apply(list)))
# 100 loops, best of 3: 8.02 ms per loop
```

Comment: Got rid of the lambda for you, since that seems to be the other answerer's USP.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to [@Alexander's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49565215/9209546) is to apply `list` to each element of a `groupby.apply(list)` object.

In general, I would prefer this solution to a `lambda` based solution, which is just a loop.

```
res = list(map(list, df.groupby('A', sort=False)['B'].apply(list)))
```

Result:

```
[[3, 4], [5, 8, 6], [6, 8], [10, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

## For large datasets I recommend using Numpy as it is faster.

*I also recommend **not** using a for-loop to sort, `df.sort_values()` is way faster.*

Here is a comparison of a 15 Million row dataset I worked on.

#### Via `Numpy`

```py
import numpy as np
df = df[['a','b']]
    
keys, values = df.sort_values('a').values.T
ukeys, index = np.unique(keys, True)
arrays = np.split(values, index[1:])
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':ukeys,'b':[list(a) for a in arrays]})
```

```
NUMPY
Total time: 102.379 s for 15,397,309 rows
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     3         1    1205208.0 1205208.0      1.2    
     4         1   60671365.0 60671365.0     59.3   
     5         1   16897187.0 16897187.0     16.5    
     6         1    1430774.0 1430774.0      1.4     
     7         1   22174794.0 22174794.0     21.7     
     8         1          4.0      4.0      0.0
```

#### With Pandas 'Groupby'

```
df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(list)
```

```
PANDAS GROUPBY
Total time: 146.23 s for 15,397,309 rows

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     3         1    1181714.0 1181714.0      0.8     
     4         1  145048477.0 145048477.0     99.2      
     5         1          3.0      3.0      0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches :

data is:

```
with open('textrr','r') as f:
    data=[line.split() for line in f.readlines()]
```

first approach using collections.defaultdict()

```
d=collections.defaultdict(list)

for item in data:
    d[item[0]].append(item[1])

print([i for i in d.values() if i[0].isdigit()])
```

output:

order will be not same :

```
[['10', '1'], ['6', '8'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '8', '6']]
```

using itertools.grouby:

```
import itertools
print([[sub[1] for sub in i] for j,i in itertools.groupby(data,key=lambda x:x[0]) if list(j)[0].isdigit()])
```

output:

order will be same

```
[['3', '4'], ['5', '8', '6'], ['6', '8'], ['10', '1']]
```

At last if you don't want to use any import then you can try manual approach:

```
groupby={}

for item in data:
    if item[0].isdigit() and item[0] not in groupby:
        groupby[item[0]]=[item[1]]
    elif item[0].isdigit():
        groupby[item[0]].append(item[1])

print(groupby.values())
```

output:

```
[['10', '1'], ['3', '4'], ['6', '8'], ['5', '8', '6']]
```